# Batch script to delete subfolder and its contents which are older than 30 minutes

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need a Windows 7 batch script which deletes sub-folder and its contents which are older than 30 minutes

e.g : forfiles -p %dump_path% -m *.* -d -%max_days% -c "cmd  /c del /q @path"

The above code is just an example and not the proper solution.

Comment: `for /d %a in (*) do @echo %~ta` <--- run this in a cmd prompt and tell me one of the lines.

Comment: Hi can you give complete script which actually deletes the files in a folder which are more than 30 minutes older  ?  The command which you pasted displays simply the date and timestamp of the folders inside and not even the file

Answer (score 1):

This will `echo` filenames in the same folder which are over 30 minutes old by last modified date.  Remove the echo from `echo del "%~1"` to enable it after testing.

```
@echo off
if /i not "%~1"=="debug" set debug=::
:: Wmic removes regional differences
:: XP Pro can have some filename errors due to the short filename bug

setlocal

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "stamp=%YYYY% %MM% %DD% %HH% %Min%"

%debug% echo current time "%stamp%"

call :DateToMinutes %stamp% NowMins

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir * /a-d /b ^|find /v /i "%~nx0"') do call :CheckMins "%%~fa"
pause
goto :EOF

:CheckMins
set "filestamp="
set "filemins="
set "MinsOld="
set "YY=" & set "YYYY=" & set "MM=" & set "DD="
set "HH=" & set "Min=" & set "Sec=" & set "dt="
set "file=%~sf1"

:: can use CreationDate instead of lastmodified

WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name="%file:\=\\%" get lastmodified | find "." >file.tmp
for /f %%a in (file.tmp) do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "filestamp=%YYYY% %MM% %DD% %HH% %Min%"
del file.tmp 2>nul

%debug% echo file time    "%filestamp%"


if not defined yyyy goto :EOF

call :DateToMinutes %filestamp% FileMins

set /a MinsOld=%NowMins%-%FileMins%
%debug% echo Now:%NowMins% File:%FileMins% Fileage:%minsold% "%~1"
%debug% pause
if %MinsOld% gtr 30 echo del "%~1"
goto :EOF

:DateToMinutes
setlocal
set yy=%1&set mm=%2&set dd=%3&set hh=%4&set nn=%5
if 1%yy% LSS 200 if 1%yy% LSS 170 (set yy=20%yy%) else (set yy=19%yy%)
set /a dd=100%dd%%%100,mm=100%mm%%%100
set /a z=14-mm,z/=12,y=yy+4800-z,m=mm+12*z-3,j=153*m+2
set /a j=j/5+dd+y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-2472633
if 1%hh% LSS 20 set hh=0%hh%
if /i {%nn:~2,1%} EQU {p} if "%hh%" NEQ "12" set hh=1%hh%&set/a hh-=88
if /i {%nn:~2,1%} EQU {a} if "%hh%" EQU "12" set hh=00
if /i {%nn:~2,1%} GEQ {a} set nn=%nn:~0,2%
set /a hh=100%hh%%%100,nn=100%nn%%%100,j=j*1440+hh*60+nn
endlocal&set %6=%j%&goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks bro this was helpful ..but I am getting a prompt "press any key to continue..." everytime I run this batch file . how can we eliminate this

Comment: Change `pause` above the `Goto :EOF` to `:: pause` or remove the `pause`

Comment: Hi ..actually there is one problem when we schedule it in the windows Task Scheduler it starts deleting the windows system files also. So iit would be better if we can provide folder path in the SCRIPT itslef . can paste the script where we provide the folder path and there it will delete the files which are older than 30 minutes

Comment: can you please paste the script where we provide the folder path and there it will delete the files which are older than 30 minutes

Comment: Are you deleting local files on the PC or network files?  If they are local files then it just needs a command like `cd /d "d:\folder"`

Comment: no actually I have to test on servers where there will be folder structure like C:\xpr\preview\   . So in this folder we need to delete the pdf files which are older than 30 minutes

Comment: On the line after `setlocal` near the top put `cd /d "c:\xpr\preview"`